# Spring Data - Can't update entity with @ManyToOne relations

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data

I got a simple **SessionEntity**:

```
public class SessionEntity {
...

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NonNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", nullable = false)
    CustomerEntity customerEntity;

...
}
```

And **CustomerEntity**:

```
public class CustomerEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NonNull
    private String territory;

    @NonNull
    private String code;

}
```

After the first transaction, I want to update SessionEntity with new CustomerEntity data using method:

```
@Query("update SessionEntity session "
    + "set session.customerEntity =:customerEntity "
    + "where "
    + "session.id =:sessionId")
Option<SessionEntity> updateCustomerForSession(@Param("sessionId") String sessionId, @Param("customerEntity") CustomerEntity customerEntity);
```

But nothing happen and in Postgres, I got still the same customer_id. Also, method one level above is `public` and `@Transactional` (`SessionRepository` - java class).
What is wrong with this solution?

Comment: I think you have to annotate `updateGameForSession` method with `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying` for spring data to commit the changes.

Comment: still not working. I think the problem is with the relation ManyToOne and this is a blocker for a correct update...

Comment: You're using spring data, have you tried just modifying and persisting the entity?
Use a setter to change customerEntity in SessionEntity and then just call the .save(sessionEntity) method in your CrudRepository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things which must be fixed. First, as Igor mentioned, I must add `@ Modifying` and second, method `updateCustomerForSession` must return int or void.